# UI Router stops working when operating with arrays

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Let's say I have an array of tags:

```
$scope.tagArray = ['monkey', 'giraffe'];
```

And then do a:

```
$location.search('tags', $scope.tagArray);
```

Then is working perfectly first time - The URL changes to something like:

http://localhost:8000/#/?tags=monkey&tags=giraffe

But... If I change the array to let's say:

```
$scope.tagArray = ['monkey'];
```

And run my search again:

```
$location.search('tags', $scope.tagArray);
```

Then the URL is still:

http://localhost:8000/#/?tags=monkey&tags=giraffe

I've even tried to parse undefined as a parameter to $location.search, but as soon as I've searched for an array - I cannot change 'tags' again.

Has anybody experienced the same? or perhaps have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was actually just to reset the $state.params everytime someone click's on the search button.

```
$state.params = [];
```

And after the reset I make all the $location.search. I don't think this is the best way, but it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Because it updates first param.

Documentation:

> If search is a string or number, then paramValue will override only a
>   single search property.

I think the proper way is to use object param  in this case instead string:

```
$location.search({ tags: 'monkey' });
```

Comment: But it doesn't explain to me why, as soon as I've successfully searched for an array, I can't change the "$location.search('tags'" at all - Not even if I try do to: 
    $location.search({ tags: 'monkey' });